# Cannot create and populate list type System.Collections.ICollection

Tags: c#, arraylist, json.net, icollection

The exact error is `Cannot create and populate list type System.Collections.ICollection. Path'[0].assocPosition.assocJobtitle.employees''`

I have this method

```
public static ArrayList Get<T>(string url)
{
    using (var response = _httpClient.GetAsync(baseUrl + url).Result)
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var customerJsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(customerJsonString);
            var arrayList = new ArrayList(list.Count);
            foreach (T item in list)
            {
                arrayList.Add(item);
            }
            return arrayList;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

where after putting breaking point i see that the problem is that the object doesnt deserialize properly.

```
public static ArrayList EmployeeAssignmentFinder_FindAll()
{
    return HttpCaller.Get<EmployeeAssignment>("WorkflowEngine/EmployeeAssignmentFinder_FindAll");
}
```

The HttpGet inside the controller:

```
[HttpGet("WorkflowEngine/EmployeeAssignmentFinder_FindAll")]
        public IActionResult WorkflowEngineEmployeeAssignmentFinder_FindAll()
{
    return Ok(_engine.VC.EmployeeAssignmentFinder_FindAll());
}
```

The EmployeeAssignment class has inside:

```
private Position m_Position;
public Position AssocPosition 
{
    get { return m_Position; }
    set { m_Position = value; }
}
```

The Position Class has inside:

```
private Jobtitle m_AssocJobtitle;
public Jobtitle AssocJobtitle 
{
    get { return m_AssocJobtitle; }
    set { m_AssocJobtitle = value; }
}
```

And Jobtitle class has inside:

```
private ICollection m_Employees;
public ICollection Employees
{
    get{ return m_Employees; }
    set { m_Employees = value;}
}
```

It might there is a conflict from `ICollection` to `ArrayList`.

Comment: Take the json that is coming into your web service and paste it into http://QuickType.io to get a set of classes that work for it..

Comment: Related: [How to Serialize and Deserialize ArrayList of Arrays by using Json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41564842/3744182).

Answer (score 0):

Try  to replace ICollection by  ICollection of T  since the last one is used by EF.

```
private ICollection<Employee> m_Employees
public ICollection<Employee> Employees
{
   get { return m_Employees; }
   set { m_Employees = value; }
}
```

and IMHO you should  use List instead of ArrayList, since it is net 5+ already, not net 1.O

```
public static List<T> Get<T>(string url)
{
    using (var response = _httpClient.GetAsync(baseUrl + url).Result)
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var customerJsonString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(customerJsonString);
        
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static List<EmployeeAssignment> EmployeeAssignmentFinder_FindAll()
{
   return HttpCaller.Get<EmployeeAssignment>("WorkflowEngine/EmployeeAssignmentFinder_FindAll");
}
```

Comment: I still getting the same error , also the whole solution depends from ArrayList.

Comment: @Christos Fix the whole solution. You can't use array list,  it was used 20 years ago.

Comment: I believe the key change here is using a generic version of [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=net-5.0) because [standard one](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.collections.icollection?view=net-5.0) doesn't have `Add()` method, and hence JSON.NET just cannot instantiate it. The issue is not related to `ArrayList` and you don't have to  remove it. @Christos are you using generic version of this interface now? Still not working?

Comment: @Christos  You can leave array  list for now , but it looks radicuolus and can cause problems in the future, but try  to replace ICollection by ICollection<T> since this is use by EF.

Comment: I tried to replace ICollection by ICollection<T> but now the programm doesnt load the Employees at all. I need to keep ArrayList even it is very old and maybe change something in Get method.