# Json.NET custom deserialize to multiple properties using a JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

Say I have some video POCO with a description property which contains some text followed by tags in the form of `[foo,bar]`. I would like to extract the tags from the description, remove it from the description and add the tags to the `Tags` property.

I just want to custom deserialize the `Description` property in a custom [JsonConverter](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) and let Json.Net deserialize the other properties as usual. I tried calling `serializer.Deserialize<MyVideo>(reader)` but this will trigger my converter again, creating a recursive loop.

So is it possible to just handle the `Description` and `Tags` properties myself and let Json.Net deserialize everything else somehow?

**Sample of the MyVideo POCO:**

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(VideoDescriptionConverter))]
public class MyVideo
{
   [JsonProperty("description")]
   public string Description { get; set; }

   public IList<string> Tags { get; set; }

   // <more properties>
}
```

**My `VideoDescriptionConverter.ReadJson` method:**

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
   // This will recursively loop so doesn't work:
   var video = serializer.Deserialize<MyVideo>(reader);
   //video.Description = <extract description and tags>
   //video.Tags = ...
   return video;
}
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Custom deserializer only for some fields with json.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41510242/3744182)?

Comment: @dbc Thanks, didn't see that one, looks like I just needed to call `serializer.Populate` instead.