# Deserialize physically incompatible JSON with domain model

Tags: c#, json, json.net, restsharp

I'm consuming a rest api using Restsharp. The response of the api has this structure.

```
{
    "resourceId": "0014b07-92sl-si90",
    "property": [
        {
            "name": "prop1",
            "value": "-1.0"
        },
        {
            "name": "prop2",
            "value": "0.0"
        },
        {
            "name": "prop3",
            "value": "1000.0"
        },
        {
            "name": "prop4",
            "value": "Microsoft Windows"
        },
        {
            "name": "prop5",
            "value": "42917.0"
        }]
}
```

I want to deserialize this response  to this domain model.

```
public class DomainModel 
{

    public double Prop1 {get; set;}

    public double Prop2 {get; set;}

    public double Prop3 {get; set;}

    public string Prop4 {get; set;}

}
```

As you can see I only need a subset of the JSON response properties and the response cannot be deserialized directly to a domain object.

Please how can I solve this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: Please more describe it. How we can save string value in an integer variable. There is no problem with losing the data? If you show a sample can be helpful.

Comment: Take a look a this answer. You probably need a custom deserialization: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510242/custom-deserializer-only-for-some-fields-with-json-net

Comment: @SaeidAmini it's not a problem I can make all the properties string properties. The problem is how can I deserialize them to that  domain model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class DomainModel
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }

    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public string Prop3 { get; set; }

    public string Prop4 { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = @"{
                        ""resourceId"": ""0014b07 - 92sl - si90"",
                        ""property"": [
                            {
                                ""name"": ""prop1"",
                                ""value"": ""-1.0""
                            },
                            {
                                ""name"": ""prop2"",
                                ""value"": ""0.0""
                            },
                            {
                                ""name"": ""prop3"",
                                ""value"": ""1000.0""
                            },
                            {
                                ""name"": ""prop4"",
                                ""value"": ""Microsoft Windows""
                            },
                            {
                                ""name"": ""prop5"",
                                ""value"": ""42917.0""
                            }]
                    }";
        var parsedJason = JObject.Parse(json);

        DomainModel result = new DomainModel();
        var jsonValues = parsedJason["property"].Select(x => ((JObject)x)).ToList();

        var props = typeof(DomainModel).GetProperties();
        jsonValues.ForEach(x =>
        {
            var jsonPropName = x.GetValue("name").ToString();
            var jsonPropValue = x.GetValue("value").ToString();

            var prop = props.Where(p => p.Name.ToUpper() == jsonPropName.Trim().ToUpper()).FirstOrDefault();
            if (prop != null)
                prop.SetValue(result, jsonPropValue, null);
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: This solves the problem. Thank you sir for the effort  to help me.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Json.NET and use the JsonProperty attribute as described in this answer:
[.NET NewtonSoft JSON deserialize map to a different property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915503/net-newtonsoft-json-deserialize-map-to-a-different-property-name)

Comment: I'm not sure the JsonProperty will deal with changing the types or data structure

Comment: Giving that all objects is the property array come with the structure {"name" : "prop-name", "value" : "prop-value" } , I dont think JsonProperty is useful here. Can you edit the response to include an example for my json response ?

Answer (score 1):

You can either deserialize the response to this class:

```
public class MyResponse
{
    public string resourceId {get;set;}
    public List<MyProperty> property {get;set;}
}

public class MyProperty
{
    public string name {get;set;}
    public string value {get;set;}
}
```

Then convert MyResponse to DomainModel:

```
DomainModel myDomainModel = new DomainModel();
myDomainModel.Prop1 = myResponse.property.Where(c=>c.name =="prop1").SingleOrDefault()?.value;
myDomainModel.Prop2 = myResponse.property.Where(c=>c.name =="prop3").SingleOrDefault()?.value;
myDomainModel.Prop2 = myResponse.property.Where(c=>c.name =="prop3").SingleOrDefault()?.value;
myDomainModel.Prop4 = myResponse.property.Where(c=>c.name =="prop4").SingleOrDefault()?.value;
```

Or build your logic into a [custom deserializer](https://bytefish.de/blog/restsharp_custom_json_serializer/).

Comment: I'm aware of this solution, but I cannot use it , because It will not be efficient in my case. Could you please edit the response with a custom Json deserializer,