# Convert decimals to integer when deserializing JSON using Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: .net, json.net

Is it possible to convert decimals to integer when deserializing JSON using Newtonsoft.Json?

Suddenly our service is receiving JSON data containing decimal values where int types are expected, example: 18483.0.

As a result exceptions are thrown like "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Input string '18483.0' is not a valid integer."

Obviously this specific property is defined as integer, and I prefer not to change it to some decimal type, but to convert the input to int, and stripping the decimals (which are always .0 anyway).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom deserializer only for some fields with json.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41510242/custom-deserializer-only-for-some-fields-with-json-net)

Comment: Can you show an example of json you have received?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a custom generic `JsonConverter` like below :

```cs
public class CustomIntConverter : JsonConverter<int>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, int value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
    }

    public override int ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, int existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);
    }
}
```

It tries to cast it to an integer if it fails then it casts it to a double and then to an int. You can use it like below :

```cs
var json = @"{""B"":42.0}";
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(json, new CustomIntConverter());
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y2bSg7)

**Edit**
Applied @vernou's suggestion

Comment: Using a safe cast `return reader.Value as int ?? ((int)(double)reader.Value);` might be a simpler method than blindly casting and catching an exception

Comment: I tested, it don't work. Json.Net return integer as `long`. Then `reader.Value` is a `long` and the cast to `int` or `double` fail. You can reproduce with `var json = @"{""B"":42}";`.

Comment: It's manage more case : `return Convert.ToInt32(reader.Value);`

Comment: @vernou indeed Json.Net has its default as `long`

Answer (score 4):

you can create a custom property converter

```
    var json = @"{ ""StringProperty"":""StringProperty"", ""IntProperty"":29.0}";

    var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Test>(json);

public class Test
{
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DoubleToIntConverter))]
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }
}
    
public class DoubleToIntConverter : JsonConverter<int>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, int value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(value);
    }

        public override int ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, int existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32( reader.Value);
    }
}
```